# Can you change the border color of separate instances of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have multiple projects of which I use different instances/windows of visual studio code for. Is there a way to change just the border color of each window so I can easily tell which project I'm on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Peacock](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock) extension and choose ‘Peacock: Change to a favorite color’ from the command palette.

> [image]